# Strategies to change Logback appender level at production

Tags: java, logging, logback

I package my applications as jars and wars. After deployment in production, I like to see on the logs if everything is ok, and once it is, I would like to decrease the level of these logs at runtime, without deploying a new jar/war again.

What is the strategies available to do this with logback? The only I found was to put the logback configuration outside the jar/war, so I could change the level anytime without deploying again. The problem with this is that it will create new arguments to my application, I would like to avoid this, I want to keep it simple.

Is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is no cleaner way than providing an external `logback.xml`.

Other options include using JMX to adjust the logger level or implementing an endpoint that will change the logger configuration programmatically.